# ExecutorService design pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a java application which has to be run as a Linux process. It connects to a remote system via socket connection. I have two threads which run through whole life cycle of the program. This is the brief version of my application entry point:

```
public class SMPTerminal {
    private static java.util.concurrent.ExcecutorService executor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutdownHook()));
        run(new SMPConsumer());
        run(new SMPMaintainer());
    }

    public static void run(Service callableService) {
        try {
            Future<Callable> future = executor.submit(callableService);
            run(future.get().restart());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExcecutionException e) {
            // Program will shutdown
        }
    }
}
```

This is `Service` interface:

```
public interface Service() {
    public Service restart();
}
```

And this is one implementation of `Service` interface:

```
public class SMPConsumer implements Callable<Service>, Service {
    @Override
    public Service call() throws Exception {
        // ...
        try {
            while(true) {
                // Perform the service
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
        return this; // Returns this instance to run again
    }
  public Service restart() {
      // Perform the initialization
      return this;
  }
}
```

I reached this structure after I have headaches when a temporary IO failure or other problems were causing my application shutdown. Now If my program encounters a problem it doesn't shutdown completely, but just initializes itself from scratch and continues. But I think this is somewhat weired and I am violating OOP design rules. My questions

- Is this kind of handling failures correct or efficient?
- what problems do I may encounter in future?
- Do I have to study about any special design pattern for my problem?

Comment: You might want to look into using a `BlockingQueue` that would act as a load balancer, you might just be overloading your `ExcecutorService` to the point where it is unable to keep up with all the requests.

Comment: @PeterK the `ExecutorService` service just runs to threads and I run each thread (`Service` interface implementation) if the thread is interrupted due to an IO, etc exception which cannot be handled from within the thread. Also I am using a Messaging Queue inside the `SMPConsumer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have noticed, but your `run` method waits for the `callableService` to finish execution before it returns. So you are not able to start two services concurrently. This is because [`Future.get()` waits until the task computation completes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--).

```
public static void run(Service callableService) {
    try {
        Future<Callable> future = executor.submit(callableService);
        run(future.get().restart()); // <=== will block until task completes!
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExcecutionException e) {
        // Program will shutdown
    }
}
```

(You should have noticed that because of the `InterruptionException` that must be caught - it indicates that there is some blocking, long running operation going on).

This also renders the execution service useless. If the code that submits a task to the executor always waits for the task to complete, there is no need to execute this task via executor. Instead, the submitting code should call the service directly.

So I assume that blocking is not inteded in this case. Probably your `run` method should look something like that:

```
public static void run(Service callableService) {
    executor.submit(() -> {
        Service result = callableService.call();
        run(result.restart());
        return result;
    });
}
```

This code snippet is just basic, you might want to extend it to handle exceptional situations.

Comment: Oh yes that makes the `ExecutorService` unusable!

Answer (score 0):

- Is this kind of handling failures correct or efficient? That depends on context of application and how you are using error handling.
- May encounter situation where I/O failures etc. are not handled properly.
- Looks like you are already using Adapter type design pattern. Look at Adapter design pattern http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html